# Mutate within map of a list within list

Tags: r, list, purrr

How can I move the value g into a column in df using map?

```
r<-data.frame(o=runif(n = 50),m=rep(c("A","N"),25))
te<-data.frame(o=runif(n = 50),m=rep(c("G","H"),25))
aq<-list(f=list(df=r,g=0),g2=list(df=te,g=5))
```

the expected result after str is:

```
List of 2
 $ f :List of 2
  ..$ df:'data.frame':  50 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ o: num [1:50] 0.785 0.253 0.228 0.323 0.332 ...
  .. ..$ m: chr [1:50] "A" "N" "A" "N" ...
  .. ..$ g: num [1:50] 0
  ..$ g : num 0
 $ g2:List of 2
  ..$ df:'data.frame':  50 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ o: num [1:50] 0.0271 0.6264 0.1487 0.2008 0.6946 ...
  .. ..$ m: chr [1:50] "G" "H" "G" "H" ...
  .. ..$ g: num [1:50] 5
  ..$ g : num 5
```

`map(aq,~mutate(.$df$g=.$g))` does not work. Any other idea how this can be done?

Comment: How about  `Map(cbind, lapply(aq, "[[", 1), g=lapply(aq, "[[", 2))`

Comment: I get the correct df´s, but f$g and g2$g are missing (although would be easy to remedy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same output as in Akrun's comment (ie one less nesting level), based on your code:

```
map(aq, ~ dplyr::mutate(.x$df, g = .x$g))
```

Simple edit to get your desired structure:

```
map(aq, ~ list(df = dplyr::mutate(.x$df, g = .x$g), g = .x$g))
```

(Edit: per Misha's comment, this is working with the development version of `purrr` (`0.2.2.9000`) but not with the current CRAN version (`0.2.2`). Don't know why yet).

Comment: Both these throw the following error: Error: invalid subscript type 'list'

Comment: What is in your workspace `ls()`? Maybe a conflicting `g` or `df`?
Try being super defensive with quotes maybe: `map(aq, ~ list("df" = dplyr::mutate(.x[["df"]], "g" = .x[["g"]]), "g" = .x[["g"]]))`

Comment: Nope. cannot find any conflicts. What version purrr and dplyr are you on?

Comment: R `3.3.1`, dplyr `0.5.0`, purrr `0.2.2.9000`

Comment: After upgrading to the development version of purrr (0.2.2.9000) it worked. Thx.